# How to concatenate two fields for search with NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nspredicate

For example, I have object like `@{@"firstName":@"aaa", @"lastName":@"bbb"}`.
Now I'm trying to search with next predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicateFirstName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName contains [c] %@", searchString];
NSPredicate *predicateLastName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastName contains [c] %@", searchString];
NSPredicate *orPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate  orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicateFirstName, predicateLastName]];
searchUsersArray = [usersArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:orPredicate];
```

I need a predicate, which will be return for search string @"aa bb" users whose first name ENDED with "aa" and lastName BEGINS with @"bb"

```
NSPredicate *predicateLastName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(firstName AND lastName contains [c] %@)", searchString]
```

don't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First divide the search string in the end-part and the begin-part:

```
NSArray *parts = [@"aa bb" componentsSeperatedByString:@" "];
```

Then use `BEGINSWITH` and `ENDSWITH`:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(firstName ENDSWITH[c] %@) AND (lastName BEGINSWITH[c] %@", parts[0], parts[1]];
```

Alternatively you can add a computed property to the entity concatinating the first name and last name and then search in this property.

Comment: I need a predicate, which will be return for search string @"aa bb" users whose first name ENDED with "aa" and lastName BEGINS with @"bb".

Comment: Ah, please clarify that in your Q. Ad an example. However, I changed my answer to that.

Comment: it's good answer, but it's doesn't work properly with request like @"aa ". Look to space symbol at the end of string. Should I check for parts[1]?

Comment: If it is possible to have only one part, you should check for that. Indeed.This should be included in your Q, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this hope it help you

```
NSString *matchString =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"(.*aa|bb.*)",searchText];
NSString *predicateString = @"keyword MATCHES[c] %@";
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicateString, matchString];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword BEGINSWITH instead of contains.

```
NSPredicate *predicateFirstName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName BEGINSWITH [c] %@", searchString];
NSPredicate *predicateLastName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastName BEGINSWITH [c] %@", searchString];
```

Comment: dont use BEGINSWITH my bro, if it is undefined use contains or ==